# What is the difference between local class and local inner class

Tags: java, class

Is there any difference between these two ?

I cannot find any reference for `local inner class` [Here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html).

And many sources have used this term. EG [here](http://www.javatpoint.com/local-inner-class)

Answer (score 3):

[Local Classes are Similar To Inner Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html#local-classes-are-similar-to-inner-classes)

An inner class is just a class inside a class. A local class is an inner class declared inside of a block.

Answer (score 3):

The reference is inside [Nested Classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) in the first link:

> ### Nested Classes
>
> The Java programming language allows you to define a class within another class.
>
> (...)
>
> **Terminology**: Nested classes are divided into two categories: static and non-static. Nested classes that are declared static are called static nested classes. Non-static nested classes are called inner classes.
>
> (...)
>
> ### Inner Classes
>
> As with instance methods and variables, an inner class is associated with an instance of its enclosing class and has direct access to that object's methods and fields. Also, because an inner class is associated with an instance, it cannot define any static members itself.
>
> (...)
>
> There are two special kinds of inner classes: [local classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/localclasses.html) and [anonymous classes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html).
>
> ### Local classes (what you're looking for)
>
> Local classes are classes that are defined in a block, which is a group of zero or more statements between balanced braces. You typically find local classes defined in the body of a method.

In conclusion:

If you're looking for *local inner classes* they're just called *local classes*. Note that a local class is a special kind of inner classes, so *local inner class* is the same as *local class*.

Comment: No, I am not looking for `local inner class` if they exist.

Comment: @joeyrohan I don't understand your comment. If you're looking for *local inner classes* they're just called *local classes* and they are a special kind of *inner classes*. Otherwise, what are you looking for?

Comment: They haven't mentioned anywhere that local inner class are same as local class?

Comment: All local classes are inner (in the meaning *non-static*). You can add *inner* part to be explicit, but you don't have to.

Comment: Just note that "inner" *does not* mean "has an enclosing instance". Here `x` refers to an instance of an inner class with no enclosing instance: `class Outer { static Object x = new Object() {}; }` What "inner" actually means is "a nested class which cannot declare static members".